# Margins Being Ignored. Specificity Issue

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation 4 framework, and have run into an issue where the margins are being overridden by the Framework's margins, which means I am unable to apply margins to certain elements without having to use the !important keyword.

Below is my _grid.scss file, which applies the layout grid for mobile browsers.

```
%row {
    @include grid-row;
}

%columns-1 {
    @include grid-column(1);
}

%columns-2 {
    @include grid-column(2);
}

%columns-3 {
    @include grid-column(3);
}

%columns-4 {
    @include grid-column(4);
}

%columns-5 {
    @include grid-column(5);
}

%columns-6 {
    @include grid-column(6);
}

%columns-7 {
    @include grid-column(7);
}

%columns-8 {
    @include grid-column(8);
}

%columns-9 {
    @include grid-column(9);
}

%columns-10 {
    @include grid-column(10);
}

%columns-11 {
    @include grid-column(11);
}

%columns-12 {
    @include grid-column(12);
}

header {
    @extend %row;

    #branding {
        @extend %columns-6;
    }

    #main-navigation {
        @extend %columns-6;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #mobile-navigation-toggle {

    }
}

#games-list {
    @extend %row;
}

#blog-entries {
    @extend %row;

    .entry {
        @extend %row;

        img {
            @extend %columns-4;
        }

        .entry-blurb {
            @extend %columns-8;
        }
    }
}

footer {

    #footer-links {
        @extend %row;

        .link-block {
            @extend %columns-6;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the affected line in the base.scss file:

```
.entry {
margin-bottom: 10px;

.entry-blurb {
    .entry-description {
    display: none;
        }
}
}
```

It will only work if I apply !important to it. Looking at the Web Dev Tools I can see the issue, but no idea how to solve it:

[image]

I think the problem may be because I am defining placeholders in SASS for the grid to avoid code bloat. Usually you would use a mixin, and the code would be included directly within the elements in CSS which would override the margins for that element then.

Answer (score 0):

Extend vs a mixin isn't going to make a difference here.  Your selector simply has too much specificity to be overridden by such a simple selector:  `#blog-entries .entry` is a more specific instance of `.entry`.

You have a few options:

- Don't nest your selectors (avoids having such a strong selector like `#blog-entries .entry` in the first place)
- Make your second selector have as much specificity (or more) than the first one
- Use `!important`